# "Send call" to iPhone from iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, bluetooth

Is it achievable to in an iPad-app somehow communicate with a pre-defined iPhone and make the iPhone call a number defined in the app?

*Example process*:
User uses the iPad app. Finds a number he/she wants to call, touches the magical button and the iPhone starts calling. Useful when iPhone is in pocket and user has a headset.

If possible I want this to work *without* installing anything on the iPhone. So for example by interfacing with bluetooth. If not possible without installing anything on the iPhone, how could it be achievable by installing something?

I'm grateful for any advice in this matter. I'm not looking for code examples but rather the *best technical* solution considering my circumstances and wishes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is possible to connect two devices, using [Game Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html), [Bonjour](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000119i) or even setting up one of them as a server with [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket).

Just install your app(s) on both devices and then, depending on your choice of approach, [The trick is just discovering the IP of the other device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/811366/237509).

So if you for example got an iPad app with the call button, and an iPhone for doing the calling, then just let the first for example TCP post to the other.

Maybe you can start a call from the iPhone without the user having to touch the phone in her pocket this way, but @tom-van-der-woerdt seem to know more about that than I do.

Comment: Good links and very informative answer. +1 and marked as answer!

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no. At least not without a jailbreak.

Developers aren't allowed to directly access the phone routines on an iPhone. You can present a Yes/No option at most, but actually calling always requires user interaction.

And without even installing software: you'd need the iPad to get the iPhone to do stuff. I'm rather sure you don't get that level of control over Bluetooth either. The iPhone could accept the call command, but the iPad couldn't send it.

Comment: So in no way (even if a special app is included in the process) could the user allow the iPad to open up calls on the iPhone? Not even with a specific app for this purpose? Let's say the user has a headset connected to the iPhone, could he/she somehow click the button on the headset to accept the outgoing call request?

Comment: That is correct. The headset will control the music, not the application. You could present a `tel://` URL to the user which will prompt a call button. Of course, pressing `OK` would violate the laws in most countries.

Comment: Why would it violate any law that the user chooses to call a number?

Comment: I assumed that this is an application that would make it easier to call while driving. If it is not, disregard my previous comment. If it is: a lot of countries have laws against using phones while driving.

Comment: as stated, the answer to your question is no... UNLESS you are willing to install a companion app on your iPhone.  Then you can do all sorts of magic... assuming your companion iPhone app is running.

Answer (score 2):

The closest actual solution would be to send a text message to the iPhone using a web service instructing the person to call that number (it would appear as a link anyway).  I hope that's an option for you.  (A free alternative would be to send an email to the phone, instead, but it's not as nice for the user experience)

Comment: I like your line of thought. However, since this solution requires the user to interact with the phone I realized that an app could achieve the same effect. This solution would be a perfect fall back solution though, thx.

Answer (score 1):

While Tom van der Woerdt is correct with the fact that user interaction is required, you could consider building in VOIP on a custom application. (A lot of work)

You could for example have the iPad tell the iPhone to load a webview (like a URL) that will give the phone a tel:// link. (Still the user needs to accept the dialog)

Ah, another solution. Configure a service on your severs to initiate a call to the iPhone connected to the desired number. This way a headset should be able to accept the call.

Comment: Great idea. That might not be impossible actually.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly easy, at least with three technical approaches:

1. notify/push your iPhone device with a custom URL, like "tel:your_number", and open it
2. pass the same URL with a bluetooth connection
3. Use a web/REST tier to store the URL a read it from your target device

High level answer/approaches though...