# Initiate iPhone call from iPad via Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, core-telephony

It has been a few years since this topic was last discussed, and given the awesome improvements to Bluetooth with iOS's 6 & 7, I figured I'd pose the question again. See 2011 answer here: ["Send call" to iPhone from iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643492/send-call-to-iphone-from-ipad)

- Is it possible to have an app that establishes a Bluetooth pairing between and iPhone and iPad, and phone calls may be initiated by tapping a phone number on the iPad, confirming the desire to initiate a call, and then have that call begin on the iPhone?

I imagine the iPhone would either run a complete copy of the app, with iPhone capable storyboards, or at least a companion app just meant to complete this pairing.

Going even further, is it possible to have the iPhone message back to the iPad indicating that the phone call, which originated from tapping on the iPad, has completed, and the iPad may update its views to, say, allow for a "call quality" pick list, or something of that nature?

I know its possible to tell generally what is happening related to the Core Telephony of the device, and return to my app at the end of the phone call (as opposed to phone.app) using this code. Note the `telprompt`, as opposed to just `tel`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://123456789"]];
```

(Thanks, [frin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028329/ios-4-2-return-to-app-after-phone-call/10635015#10635015)!)

But how can I verify that the iPhone has completed the call, and should notify the iPad? I have seen this code in the past, but I can't seem to piece this part together.