# How to forward a call from one iOS device to Other device in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7

I want to forward a call from iPhone device to iPad and viceversa. I used Phone URL Scheme but it is not working. Can any one suggest me How it is doable?

Comment: You can't make phone calls from iPad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible.If there is a way to do so, it's only through a private API, which will cause your app to be rejected from the App Store.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any private API's exist for this?? coz I need to use it in enterprise app. So not to worry about Apple Rejection.

Comment: You can find it on Github,try searching for that.I hope these 2 links help you a little bit..1) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTA4dyIwTB8

  2) http://www.cutemachine.com/iphone-productivity-quick-tip/how-to-divert-calls-on-the-iphone-with-gsm-codes/

Comment: I think the first link wont work now. I saw some posts saying that the first approach is not working.

Comment: @MonishKumar just found this link..hope this will help you..http://stackoverflow.com/a/8669686/1865424